# Linest function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the `linest` function in excel and I tried converting them to VBA, I don't see the constant value b getting generated when I do in VBA.

```
source_worksheet.Range("A" & nRows).FormulaR1C1 = "=LINEST(known y,,TRUE)
```

When I try in Excel,

```
=LINEST(know y's,,True)
```

I see 2 columns generated, one the slope and other for constant value B. But with VBA I only see one value generated that's the slope and I don't see the constant value B generated even though I had set the option to be true. Any idea how to get both the columns printed in VBA.

Comment: Difficult to see what's going on without the exact code you used and the values of the various variables you're using...  To begin with though, you're only entering the formula in a single cell, but it's intended to be entered in 2 cells, using `FormulaArray`

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?  Specifically,  does it support Dynamic Arrays (Spill ranges)?.  And please post the code you've tried